# Master detail XML serialize in c#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am new for XML, basically I have class like this:

```
public class Items:List<string>
{
    private string _name;
    public string Product
    {
    get {return _name;}
    set {_name=value;}
    }
}
```

I want to serialize object base on this class like this:

```
  <Items>
      <Product>product name</Product>
      <Item> A1 </Item>
      <Item> A2 </Item>
      <Item> A3 </Item>
      <Item> A4 </Item>
      <Item> A5 </Item>
   </Items>
```

My question is when I try to serialize this object,XML serialize program ignore Product element, only got this XML data:

```
<Items>
   <Item> A1 </Item>
   <Item> A2 </Item>
   <Item> A3 </Item>
   <Item> A4 </Item>
   <Item> A5 </Item>
</Items>
```

Anyone can help me to get right format XML doc.

Comment: are you using XMLWriter or XMLSerializer? You should also try to decorate your class with [XmlElement]

Comment: I do use XmlSerializer, I try to add XmlElement to decorate either Item or Production element, but it still not work for me. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XmlSerializer` (and a lot of other code) treats things as **either** an item **or** (exclusive) a list. You should not subclass a list and properties: you should have a type that *has* a list and *has* a property.

```
[XmlRoot("Items")]
public class Foo {
    public string Product {get;set;}

    private readonly List<string> items = new List<string>();
    [XmlElement("Item")]
    public List<string> Items {get{return items;}}
}
```

Comment: I trid you class, I got this:
<Items>
   <Product> abc </Product>
   <Items>
      <Item> A1 </Item>
      <Item> A2 </Item>
      <Item> A3 </Item>
      <Item> A4 </Item>
      <Item> A5 </Item>
   </Items>
</Items>
I got extra Items node.

Comment: Great, it works, I created program has some issue cause I got wrong result

Comment: @Ericyu67 an extra `Items` node happens if you don't mark it as `[XmlElement]`. Basically, it defaults to `[XmlArray]` / `[XmlArrayItem]` layout.